# TYPE_ACCELEROMETER Remove the gravity, the meaning of t/(t+dT)

Tags: android

Android developer example:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
      // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
      // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
      // and dT, the event delivery rate

      final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
}
```

alpha = 0.8 what kind of the numerical calculated?
I want to ask specific values of t and dT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, I will have to dig a little into the low-pass filter since alpha is almost the last value we get.

A Low-pass Filter is usually build in this order:

1. The [cutoff Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency) fc in Hertz that you want to cut (here the gravity is continue, so the value should be around 1Hz)
2. The [Time-constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant#Time_constants_in_electrical_circuits) τ (tau) `τ = 1/(2 * π * fc)`
3. The delta of time ∆t in second. `∆t = t2 - t1`
4. The smoothing factor α, in this case `α = τ / (τ + ∆t)`
5. The previous output and the new input in order to get the new output.

The function of `alpha` is to give more or less importance to a value. To work, the filter needs an alpha between 0 and 1. In this case the previous output (gravity) weights for 80% of the new output  and the new input (event.values) weights for 20% => `new gravity = 80% old gravity + 20% acceleration`.

`∆t` is given by the implementation of your sensor. Usually for a [`SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/hardware/SensorManager.java#SensorManager.getDelay%28int%29) it's 0.2s.

The τ is calculated from α = 0.8 and ∆t = 0.2s

Extract τ from α will give:

```
τ = (∆t * α) / (1 - α)
```

And with the previous value, you will find

```
τ  = 0.2 * 0.8 / (1 - 0.8) = 0.8
```

And with τ, you can calculate fc:

```
fc = 1 / (2 * π * τ) = 1/( 2 * 3.14 * 0.8) = 0.2Hz.
```

Comment: thank,I know t is given by the implementation of  sensor.  α = 0.8 how obtained?  fc what to do with?

Comment: @嘚嘚9468 Alpha is obtained from the cut off frequency (fc). The low filter will keep the acceleration value which have a frequency inferior to fc but will reduce the acceleration value which have a frequency superior to fc. Here you want to keep the gravity (which is a constant acceleration of 9.8m/s²) and discard acceleration caused by the phone movement. So you will have to choose a very small fc, like 0.2Hz to only keep the acceleration of the gravity. After you've chosen fc, you can calculate alpha.

Comment: I should go to tutorial about mathematics, these things come out, thank you!

Comment: You can check this [link](http://www.kircherelectronics.com/blog/index.php/11-android/sensors/8-low-pass-filter-the-basics) . It explains the low filter used on android and tells you the difference between the filter in android and the filter on wikipedia (take care of alpha)

Answer (score 0):

@xiaomi

> Your answer：The smoothing factor α, in this case **α = τ / (τ + ∆t)**

But I get it from Wikipedia：[Low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization)

```
// Return RC low-pass filter output samples, given input samples,
// time interval dt, and time constant RC
function lowpass(real[0..n] x, real dt, real RC)
    var real[0..n] y
    var real α := dt / (RC + dt)
    y[0] := α * x[0]
    for i from 1 to n
        y[i] := α * x[i] + (1-α) * y[i-1]
    return y
```

var real **α := dt / (RC + dt)**.
Is inconsistent with your statement, and I want to know which one is right

Comment: Looks like you want to leave a comment on Xiaomi's answer, I know that it looks good the way you you did it but it might confuse new people looking at this answer because per se it does not answer you question (it actually leaves more doubts)